# ¿Cómo eliminar un registro que está referido en otra tabla?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

deseo eliminar un registro pero no puedo ya que hace se encuentra haciendo referencia a otra tabla, quiero borrar esa referencia y de ahí eliminar el registro. 
Mi función para eliminar es la siguiente.

```
 $scope.userDelete = function(id){
    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el usuario?",
        title: "CONFIRMACION",
        callback: function(result) {
            if(result){ 
            $scope.user.$delete({id:id}, function(){
                    $scope.userList();
                });
                }
        }
    });
}
```

pero el error que se presenta al ejecutar es el siguiente:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

en mi controlador de java tengo lo siguiente:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<User> delete(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @PathVariable("id") int id){
    User user = userDAO.findOneById(id);
    //Borrar registro
    userDAO.delete(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Tu problema parece ser del servicio de Java implementado con Hibernate. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta para agregar la información puntual de Java. Es muy probable que se trate de un tema de mapeo de entidades.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de editar la pregunta no sé si ahí se comprenda mejor.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes dos opciones, una es borrar manualmente los registros con otro método en otro dao, o bien declarar tus modelos dependientes como cascade

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   protected User addressOwner;
```

Recuerda que para esto el modelo ser generado por el mismo persistence, si hiciste tu base de datos manual debes agregar el cascade con sql dependiendo tu servidor de base de datos.